# Combined effect of linear transformation?

Tags: linear-transformations

> When two linear transformations are preformed one after another, the
>   combined effect may not always be a linear transformation. Is it true?

What I thought is below.

Let $T$ and $U$ are linear transformation which is $T:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$, $U:\Bbb{R}^m\to \Bbb{R}^l$ then they have to satisfy the condition of linear transformation, so I can write as below.

1. $T(cu+dv) =cT(u)+dT(v)$
2. $U(eu+fv)=eU(u)+fU(v)$

for some constants $c,d,e,v$.

If $T$ is first used and after $U$,

$U(T(cu+dv))=U(cT(u)+dT(v))=cU(T(u))+dU(T(v))$

Combined effect of $U$ and $T$ always satisfies linear transformation, then it is true.

This solution is very poor, so I want to find correct solution. How can I fix it or solve?

Comment: That solution isn't very poor, it looks perfectly fine to me. Yes, the composition of linear transforms is always linear.

Comment: Thanks for the verification.

Answer (score 1):

To be more vigorous you should say "for all scalars c,d,e,f in R and vectors u,v in R^n" and pick a different pair for doing U over R^m, though you may want to generalise to arbitrary vector fields for a more complete proof.